# Run PowerShell script when container starts

Tags: powershell, docker, dockerfile

How to run a simple PowerShell script after Docker container starts?

```
FROM  ...
ENTRYPOINT ["powershell", "C:\scripts\remotetools.ps1"]
```

or

```
FROM  ...
CMD ["powershell", "C:\scripts\remotetools.ps1"]
```

didn't work

Comment: When you specifiy the script as an entrypoint/cmd, Docker will run the script once. When the script finishes executing the container stops. Is this what you want?

Comment: Is `C:\scripts\remotetools.ps1` a path to the script in docker or a path to the script on the host?

Comment: C:\scripts\remotetools.ps1 a path in container

Comment: PS C:\> cat .\scripts\remotetools.ps1
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 15.0\Common7\IDE\Remote Debugger\x64\msvsmon.exe" ` 
              -ArgumentList "/nostatus","/silent","/noauth","/anyuser","/nosecuritywarn"

Comment: script run a start-process for Remote Debugger, i need to continue working with environment

Comment: Please clarify "didn't work".

Comment: Unable to find type [powershell,C:\scripts\remotetools.ps1]. Details: The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047) 
At line:1 char:76
+ ... erence = 'SilentlyContinue'; [powershell, C:\scripts\remotetools.ps1]
+                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (powershell,C:\scripts\remotetools.ps1:TypeName) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFoundWithMessage

Answer (score 0):

Take the ENTRYPOINT/CMD out of the dockerfile and then build the image again, and run it. find the container ID with

```
docker container ls
```

Now run your command but passed through the exec function so you can see if it works and get some better debugs:

```
docker exec <HEX_CONTAINER_ID> powershell C:\scripts\remotetools.ps1
```

you may also require the `--privileged` flag if the script doesn't run, then you may be looking at a permissions issue

Comment: docker exec <HEX_CONTAINER_ID> powershell C:\scripts\remotetools.ps1 - it works

Comment: have you tried replacing the CMD/ENTRYPOINT in the shell form?
`["powershell", "C:\scripts\remotetools.ps1"]`
replaced with
`powershell C:\scripts\remotetools.ps1`